# Regex for a number text combination

Tags: javascript, regex

sorry I'm very new to regular expressions and I need to create one that matches the following pattern:

a number of four letters (range 2000 to 3000) , one letter (A to Z) , a number of two letters (01 to 50)

So a valid expression would be for example: 2199R12 or 3000B01

I have no idea how to start. Would be very happy if someone can help.

Comment: what language ?

Comment: (2\d{3}|3000)[A-Z](0[1-9]|[1-4[[0-9]|50)

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A javascript

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example for you! `(2\d{3}|3000)[A-z](?:0[1-9]|[1-4]\d|50)` this should match only the strings you are looking for, and the link to regex101 I sent has a detailed explanation for all the individual pieces that make up the regex.

https://regex101.com/r/eq4SyY/2/

Comment: @OP Please pay particular attention to the panel on the linked page which explains what the parts of the regex do.

Comment: This will match 3999 from start.

Comment: Thanks for catching that :) I've gone ahead and fixed that now.

Answer (score 0):

here is a combination of regex and built-in language utilities to achieve that; in a clean  and readable manner :)

```js
function isValid (str){
  if(str.length != 7) return false
  let fourDigits = parseInt(str.slice(0,4))
  if(!(fourDigits >= 2000 && fourDigits <= 3000)) return false;
  let isCapitalLetter = /[A-Z]/.test(str.slice(4, 5));
  if (!isCapitalLetter) return false;
  let twoDigits = parseInt(str.slice(5, 7));
  if (!(twoDigits >= 1 && twoDigits <= 50)) return false;
  return true
}
```

---

Here is some sample test cases :

```js
function isValid (str){
  if(str.length != 7) return false
  let fourDigits = parseInt(str.slice(0,4))
  if(!(fourDigits >= 2000 && fourDigits <= 3000)) return false;
  let isCapitalLetter = /[A-Z]/.test(str.slice(4, 5));
  if (!isCapitalLetter) return false;
  let twoDigits = parseInt(str.slice(5, 7));
  if (!(twoDigits >= 1 && twoDigits <= 50)) return false;
  return true
}

console.log("2199R12", isValid("2199R12"));
console.log("3000B01", isValid("3000B01"));
console.log("4199R12", isValid("4199R12"));
console.log("2889x12", isValid("2889x12"));
console.log("2889A77", isValid("2889A77"));
console.log("2g99S12", isValid("2g99S12"));
```

Comment: Does that work if `fourDigits ` is `NaN`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton nope; fixed 

Answer (score 0):

```html
^((([2][0-9]{3})|([3][0][0][0]))[A-Z](([0-4][0-9])|[5][0]))$
```